# Enemy AI not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have recently become interested in creating games in Unity, however I have no idea how the language works (C#).

This current test "game" I was making was to make an enemy wander around on its own. I created a code that I hoped would work, but unfortunately the enemy would not move. I'm not sure what's wrong with it as I'm not getting any errors and am hoping someone can help. All of the Debug.Log values are returning as they should, but the enemy is not moving as it should.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Start(){
        findPosition();
    }


    //Variables
    public Transform enemy;

    private Vector2 position;

    /* not necessary
    private float maxPosX;
    private float maxPosY;
    private float maxNegX;
    private float maxNegY;
    */

    public float wanderSpeed = 3;

    private float totalWalkDistanceUp;
    private float totalWalkDistanceDown;
    private float totalWalkDistanceLeft;
    private float totalWalkDistanceRight;




    private void findPosition(){
        position.x = enemy.position.x;
        position.y = enemy.position.y;

        /* not neccessary
        maxPosX = position.x + 5;
        maxNegX = position.x - 5;
        maxPosY = position.y + 5;
        maxNegY = position.y -5;
        */

        Debug.Log ("Enemy position: " + position);
        //Debug.Log ("Max positive 'x' position: " + maxPosX + ". Max positive 'y' position: " + maxPosY + ". Max negative 'x' position: " + maxNegX + ". Max negative 'y' position: " + maxNegY);
        Debug.Log ("Finished!");

        enemyWalk();
    }

    private void enemyWalk(){
        //Distance Generator
        float walkDistance = Random.Range (1f, 5f);
        totalWalkDistanceUp = walkDistance + position.x;
        totalWalkDistanceDown = position.x - walkDistance;
        totalWalkDistanceRight = walkDistance + position.y;
        totalWalkDistanceLeft = position.y - walkDistance;
        Debug.Log ("Distance generated up: " + totalWalkDistanceUp + ". Distance generated down: " + totalWalkDistanceDown + ". Distance generated left: " + totalWalkDistanceLeft + ". Distance generated right: " + totalWalkDistanceRight);

        //Direction generator
        int directionGenerator = Random.Range (1, 4);

        if(directionGenerator == 1){ //up
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(totalWalkDistanceUp, 0) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: up");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 2){ //down
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(totalWalkDistanceDown, 0) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: down");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 3){ //left
            enemy.transform.Translate (new Vector2(0, totalWalkDistanceLeft) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: left");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 4){ //right
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, totalWalkDistanceRight) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: right");
        }
    }

}
```

Full code: http://www.pastebucket.com/75289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `enemyWalk` method looks okay at a glance, but the issue I see is that it's only called once.

You may want to add use the MonoBehaviour [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) method, which acts as the component's game loop. `Update` gets called once per frame, so calling `enemyWalk()` inside `Update` should see your character move:

```
private void Update () {
    enemyWalk();
}
```

Comment: This worked correctly, however is there a way to make a different update function that updates slower than 1 frame per second? The character moves a little too quickly, and it should pause for about 6 seconds before moving again if that makes sense.

Comment: [InvokeReapating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)("enemyWalk",0,1) you can use.

Comment: multiply your movements for time.deltaTime (so it can be independent from frame rate), and if it's too speedy, just divide the result every time. Another solution is to use FixedUpdate() instead of Update(), and modify from the project settings the time-step for FixedUpdate()